How can a duration scalar from Django models be implemented for Strawberry GQL?
How can Django duration model fields be exposed in a Strawberry GraphQL API? Is there a standard implementation for the ISO8601 duration format or does a custom scalar field need to be implemented?
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    my_duration = models.DurationField()


After some searching and not finding anything, here is an implementation (for my future reference and prosperity). Uses the isodate package from pypi.
import isodate
from typing import NewType
from datetime import timedelta
import strawberry
import strawberry_django

from my_app.models import MyModel

Duration = strawberry.scalar(
    NewType("Duration", timedelta),
    serialize=lambda v: isodate.duration_isoformat(v),
    parse_value=lambda v: isodate.parse_duration(v),
)

@strawberry_django.type(MyModel)
class MyModelGQLNode:
    name: strawberry.auto
    my_duration: Duration


